# Querybuilder | access property for which path is not fixed

Tags: aem, query-builder

Normally I would use filter for property like `cq:tags` as mentioned below. Here I know where cq:tags property exists in content structure:

```
group.5_group.fulltext.relPath=jcr:content/@cq:tags
group.5_group.fulltext=*location*
```

For any page where I can drop any number of component and property is inside component node, how will I add filter for such properties.

E.g. My component name is `component` and `prop` is property. Some exmaple path for `porp` can be `jcr:content/mainParsys/component/@prop` or `jcr:content/mainParsys/componen_anyrandomValue/@prop`

```
group.5_group.fulltext.relPath=what_should_be_the_path_or_filter
group.5_group.fulltext=*location*
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to search through path if it's undefined?

You can go with the `resourceType` of the component as it will remain same and try your query in [Query Debugger](http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html) as:

```
type=nt:unstructured
1_property=sling:resourceType
1_property.value=my-project/components/content/component
2_property=myprop
2_property.operation=exists
```

It worked for me to search for a property inside a component.

Comment: I think you did not understood my question. The path is always present only thing is I don't know what it would be or how to calculate it dynamically.